# Ways of Avoiding the Read-Modify-Write Anti-Pattern When Using Spring Data?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data

From Craig Ringer's [post](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/) on this topic:

> An SQL coding anti-pattern that I see quite a lot: the naïve
>   read-modify-write cycle. Here I’ll explain what this common
>   development mistake is, how to identify it, and options for how to fix
>   it.
>
> Imagine your code wants to look up a user’s balance, subtract 100 from
>   it if doing so won’t make it negative, and save it.
>
> It’s common to see this written as three steps:
>
> ```
>  SELECT balance FROM accounts WHERE user_id = 1;
>  -- in the application, subtract 100 from balance if it's above
>  -- 100; and, where ? is the new balance: 
>  UPDATE accounts SET balance = ? WHERE user_id =1;
> ```
>
> and everything will appear to work fine to the developer. However,
>   this code is critically wrong, and will malfunction as soon as the
>   same user is updated by two different sessions at the same time.
>
> **Don’t transactions prevent this?**
>
> I often have people on Stack Overflow ask things to the tune of “Don’t
>   transactions prevent this?”. Unfortunately, while great, transactions
>   aren’t magic secret sauce you can add for easy concurrency. The only
>   way to let you completely ignore concurrency issues is to LOCK TABLE
>   every table you might use before starting the transaction (and even
>   then you have to always lock in the same order to prevent deadlocks).
>
> **Avoiding the read-modify-write cycle**
>
> The best solution is often to just do the work in SQL, avoiding the
>   read-modify-write-cycle entirely.
>
> Just write: `UPDATE accounts SET balance = balance-100 WHERE user_id = 1; (sets balance=200)`

When I use Spring Data to modify my entities, I find myself inside the read-modify-write pattern all the time. Here's an example entity:

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    /** GETTERS AND SETTERS */

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long> {

    Customer findByLastName(String lastName);
}
```

And application logic:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

            // save a couple of customers
            repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));

            Customer customer = repository.findByLastName("Bauer");
            customer.setFirstName("kek");
            repository.save(customer);
        };
    }

}
```

However, here we see that the read-modify-write anti-pattern is executed. If our goal is to avoid this anti-pattern, what would be the different way of writing the code? So far the solution that I've come up with is by adding a modifying query to the repository and using that to modify. So to our `CustomerRepository` we add the following method:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update customer set first_name = :firstName where id= :id")
@Modifying
void updateFirstName(@Param("id") long id, @Param("firstName") String firstName);
```

And in our application logic becomes:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner demo(CustomerRepository repository) {
        return (args) -> {

            // save a couple of customers
            repository.save(new Customer("Jack", "Bauer"));
            repository.save(new Customer("Chloe", "O'Brian"));

            Customer customer = repository.findByLastName("Bauer");
            repository.updateFirstName(customer.getId(), "kek");
        };
    }

}
```

This works perfectly to avoid the read-modify-write anti-pattern, but it would be very tedious to write update methods into the repository for every single case of wanting to modify an entity's attribute. Is there no better way to do this in Spring Data?

Comment: The thing is, this is only an anti-pattern in some use-cases, like incrementing a value. Incrementing a value is not idempotent: if you do it twice, the sum is incremented twice. Setting a first name is idempotent: setting a first name twice just sets the first name. And if you really don't want to set the first name is someone has modified it concurrently, JPA supports optimistic (and pessimistic) locking.

Comment: @JBNizet I find that avoiding this anti-pattern is a great way to protect against lost updates. Generally, I think this is the best way to code your application logic. I'm just wondering if there's an easier way to do this in Spring Data than having to write a custom repository method for each thing you want to modify in your application logic.

Comment: If you want to do that, JPA is clearly not the right tool.

Comment: @JBNizet what would you use instead?

Comment: I would use JPA, and stick to the opinion I gave in my first comment.

Comment: @JBNizet so just rely on optimistic/pessimistic locking instead to avoid lost updates?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "lost update". In your example, if one transaction tries setting the first name to "kek", and a concurrent one tries setting the first name to "Jane", one of them will win, whether or not you use read-modify-write.

Comment: @JBNizet sometimes two clients will try to access the same row at the same time, say a different client tries to set a different last name while another one is setting a first name. I've had instances where one of the session's update is lost, i.e. the first name stayed the same. I assume this is because Spring Data applies some sort of row lock by default, but apart from the separate repository method with an update query I haven't found a different method of avoiding this kind of lost update (yes, I've tried setting all the different ISOLATION levels in @Transactional).

Comment: spring data doesn't apply any row locking. Bug again, a typical app doesn't update the firstname while another transaction updates the last name. A typical app has a form allowing to update the user information. When the user is submitted, all the columns are updated at once. If one changes the last name and the other changes the first name, one of the two will win, whether you read before updating or not. The solution to that is optimistic locking. Not reading before updating won't change anything.

Comment: this is not an anti-pattern in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works perfectly to avoid the read-modify-write anti-pattern, but it would be very tedious to write update methods into the repository for every single case of wanting to modify an entity's attribute. Is there no better way to do this in Spring Data?

TL;DR: No, that's the way to do it.

**Longer version**

JPA is built on exactly that approach:

1. Load the data into memory
2. Manipulate it in whatever way you want
3. Save the resulting data structure back to the database.

But it also has a protection built in: Optimistic locking. JPA and thus Spring Data JPA will throw an exception and rollback the transaction when a row that gets saved was changed since it got loaded, assuming you have a version column and thereby optimistic locking enabled.

So from a consistency point of view, you are fine.

Of course for updates like the one you described (updating an account balance) this is rather wasteful and the direct update would be more efficient. The `@Modify` annotation is exactly for this purpose.

On the other hand, the example you used for the annotation is idempotent so apart from possible performance benefits isn't necessary at all. And even the performance benefit disappears in many real-world applications.

This is only really relevant when the new value depends on the original value as in the account example. For most applications, these are just a few special cases that can't be abstracted over anyway so crafting the SQL statements by hand can't be avoided.

If the queries themselves are complex it might be worth it to look into Querydsl or jOOQ for crafting the queries.

Comment: @Alexay Sorry, but that is a completely independent question. Please create a separate question.